# OnClick on 0th index postion of recyclerview adapter item it also select the 7th index postion then 14th like this. Below is code snippt

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Below is the code of QuestionActivity Class where i have implemented recyclerview.

> Problem Statement

When i click on first element of recyclerview adapter then it also select the 7th position of adapter but the value is not inserted or passed from the 7th element. value is just passed from 1st element not from  7th element. When i will click on 2nd element then it also select the 8th element in adapter and also select the 16th element also and this thing is going on. i dont know what to do because i am just selecting one element in adapter but it selecting multiple element and what is the logic behind on selection of 7th element.

> Activity Class

```
  QuestionPaperAdapter questionPaperAdapter = new QuestionPaperAdapter(QuestionPaperActivity.this, response.body());
                    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(QuestionPaperActivity.this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
                    SnapHelper snapHelper = new PagerSnapHelper();
                    snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(questionPaperRecyclerView);
                    questionPaperRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
                    questionPaperRecyclerView.setAdapter(questionPaperAdapter);
```

> Adapter Class

**It's complete Adapter Class**

```
public class QuestionPaperAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<QuestionPaperAdapter.QuestionVH> {
    private static final String TAG = "QuestionPaperAdapter";
    private QuestionPaperActivity context;
    private StartTestQuestionResModel startTestDetailsModel;
    private String mediaBase = "https://amazonaws.com/media/";


    private List<StartTestQuestionListModel> startTestQuestionListModels;

    public QuestionPaperAdapter(QuestionPaperActivity context, StartTestQuestionResModel startTestDetailsModel) {
        this.context = context;
        this.startTestDetailsModel = startTestDetailsModel;

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public QuestionVH onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.question_paper_parts_fullpage, parent, false);

        startTestQuestionListModels = new ArrayList<>();
        return new QuestionVH(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final QuestionVH holder, final int position) {
if (startTestDetailsModel.getResult().get(position).getType().equals("question")) {

            holder.subjectCardOne.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Log.d(TAG, "position in question -->> " + String.valueOf(position));

            holder.questionCard.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.subjectNameTV.setText(startTestDetailsModel.getResult().get(position).getSubject());

            holder.questoinNumberTV.setText(String.valueOf(startTestDetailsModel.getResult().get(position).getQuestionNo()));
            holder.questoinTV.setText(startTestDetailsModel.getResult().get(position).getQuestion());
            holder.answerOneTV.setText(startTestDetailsModel.getResult().get(position).getA());
            holder.answerTwoTV.setText(startTestDetailsModel.getResult().get(position).getB());
            holder.answerThreeTV.setText(startTestDetailsModel.getResult().get(position).getC());
            holder.answerFourTV.setText(startTestDetailsModel.getResult().get(position).getD());



        holder.answerOneLL.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Log.d(TAG, "position in question one -->> " + String.valueOf(position));

                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                        holder.answerOneRB.setBackground(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.round_answer_cricle_solid));
                        holder.answerTwoRB.setBackground(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.round_answer_cricle));
                        holder.answerThreeRB.setBackground(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.round_answer_cricle));
                        holder.answerFourRB.setBackground(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.round_answer_cricle));
                    }


            }
        });




        holder.answerTwoLL.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    holder.answerOneRB.setBackground(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.round_answer_cricle));
                    holder.answerTwoRB.setBackground(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.round_answer_cricle_solid));
                    holder.answerThreeRB.setBackground(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.round_answer_cricle));
                    holder.answerFourRB.setBackground(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.round_answer_cricle));
                }
            }
        });


        holder.answerThreeLL.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    holder.answerOneRB.setBackground(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.round_answer_cricle));
                    holder.answerTwoRB.setBackground(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.round_answer_cricle));
                    holder.answerThreeRB.setBackground(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.round_answer_cricle_solid));
                    holder.answerFourRB.setBackground(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.round_answer_cricle));
                }
            }
        });


        holder.answerFourLL.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    holder.answerOneRB.setBackground(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.round_answer_cricle));
                    holder.answerTwoRB.setBackground(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.round_answer_cricle));
                    holder.answerThreeRB.setBackground(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.round_answer_cricle));
                    holder.answerFourRB.setBackground(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.round_answer_cricle_solid));
                }
            }
        });


    }



@Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return startTestDetailsModel.getResult().size();
    }

    public class QuestionVH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView subjectNameTVOne, questoinNumberTV, subjectNameTVTwo, subjectNameTVThree, subjectNameTVFour, questoinTV, answerOneTV, answerTwoTV, answerThreeTV, answerFourTV;
        private TextView answerOneRB, answerTwoRB, answerThreeRB, answerFourRB, instructionTV, subjectNameTV;
        private CardView subjectCardOne, subjectCardTwo, subjectCardThree, subjectCardFour, questionCard;
        private RecyclerView partOneRecyclerView, partTwoRecyclerView, partThreeRecyclerView, partFourRecyclerView;
        private LinearLayout answerOneLL, answerTwoLL, answerThreeLL, answerFourLL;
        private MathView mathview;
        private ImageView instructionImg, questoinImg, answerOneImg, answerTwoImg, answerThreeImg, answerFourImg;

        public QuestionVH(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            mathview = itemView.findViewById(R.id.mathview);
            subjectNameTV = itemView.findViewById(R.id.subjectNameTV);

            subjectCardOne = itemView.findViewById(R.id.subjectCardOne);
            instructionTV = itemView.findViewById(R.id.instructionTV);
            subjectNameTVOne = itemView.findViewById(R.id.subjectNameTVOne);

            answerTwoLL = itemView.findViewById(R.id.answerTwoLL);
            answerOneLL = itemView.findViewById(R.id.answerOneLL);
            answerThreeLL = itemView.findViewById(R.id.answerThreeLL);
            answerFourLL = itemView.findViewById(R.id.answerFourLL);


            questoinTV = itemView.findViewById(R.id.questoinTV);
            questoinNumberTV = itemView.findViewById(R.id.questoinNumberTV);
            questionCard = itemView.findViewById(R.id.questionCard);

            answerOneTV = itemView.findViewById(R.id.answerOneTV);
            answerTwoTV = itemView.findViewById(R.id.answerTwoTV);
            answerThreeTV = itemView.findViewById(R.id.answerThreeTV);
            answerFourTV = itemView.findViewById(R.id.answerFourTV);

            answerOneRB = itemView.findViewById(R.id.answerOneRB);
            answerTwoRB = itemView.findViewById(R.id.answerTwoRB);
            answerThreeRB = itemView.findViewById(R.id.answerThreeRB);
            answerFourRB = itemView.findViewById(R.id.answerFourRB);


        }
    }

}
```

if you have any doubt about above code please comment and let me know.

Comment: Share your `onBindViewHolder` code

Comment: As @RahulKhurana said, post your `onBindViewHolder` implementation and also the `onCreateViewHolder`. Chances are you're sharing your click listener between view holders

Comment: since viewholders are recycled i am suspecting that your click listener is declared in the wrong place. post your adapter code

Comment: I have updated the adapter code please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so the issue happens due to the fact that the RecyclerView recycles the viewholders.

Now your onClickListener will set the stuff on your viewholder but what happens is that when it is recycled, it is not going to be called again so the old layout still gets shown is for your case position 7 etc.

Solution:

Have a switch case in the bind viewholder which checks what was selected:

Add a variable in your Question Model and also add it's getter setter methods

```
private int answerClicked;
```

Now when the click is performed, set the answerClicked variable of the current question model to the answer clicked

```
    holder.answerOneLL.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Log.d(TAG, "position in question one -->> " + String.valueOf(position));

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    startTestDetailsModel.getResult().get(position).setAnswerClicked(1);
                    holder.answerOneRB.setBackground(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.round_answer_cricle_solid));
                    holder.answerTwoRB.setBackground(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.round_answer_cricle));
                    holder.answerThreeRB.setBackground(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.round_answer_cricle));
                    holder.answerFourRB.setBackground(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.round_answer_cricle));

                    notifyDataSetChanged();  //facepalm for me forgetting this
                }


        }
    });




    holder.answerTwoLL.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                startTestDetailsModel.getResult().get(position).setAnswerClicked(2);
                holder.answerOneRB.setBackground(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.round_answer_cricle));
                holder.answerTwoRB.setBackground(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.round_answer_cricle_solid));
                holder.answerThreeRB.setBackground(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.round_answer_cricle));
                holder.answerFourRB.setBackground(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.round_answer_cricle));

              notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    });


    holder.answerThreeLL.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                startTestDetailsModel.getResult().get(position).setAnswerClicked(3);
                holder.answerOneRB.setBackground(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.round_answer_cricle));
                holder.answerTwoRB.setBackground(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.round_answer_cricle));
                holder.answerThreeRB.setBackground(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.round_answer_cricle_solid));
                holder.answerFourRB.setBackground(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.round_answer_cricle));

              notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    });


    holder.answerFourLL.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                startTestDetailsModel.getResult().get(position).setAnswerClicked(4);
                holder.answerOneRB.setBackground(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.round_answer_cricle));
                holder.answerTwoRB.setBackground(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.round_answer_cricle));
                holder.answerThreeRB.setBackground(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.round_answer_cricle));
                holder.answerFourRB.setBackground(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.round_answer_cricle_solid));

             notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    });
```

Now add the following to your Bind Viewholder method

```
  if(startTestDetailsModel.getResult().get(position).getType().equals("question") && startTestDetailsModel.getResult().get(position).getAnswerClicked()==1){
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    holder.answerOneRB.setBackground(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.round_answer_cricle_solid));
                    holder.answerTwoRB.setBackground(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.round_answer_cricle));
                    holder.answerThreeRB.setBackground(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.round_answer_cricle));
                    holder.answerFourRB.setBackground(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.round_answer_cricle));
                }
  }else if(startTestDetailsModel.getResult().get(position).getType().equals("question") && startTestDetailsModel.getResult().get(position).getAnswerClicked()==2){
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                holder.answerOneRB.setBackground(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.round_answer_cricle));
                holder.answerTwoRB.setBackground(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.round_answer_cricle_solid));
                holder.answerThreeRB.setBackground(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.round_answer_cricle));
                holder.answerFourRB.setBackground(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.round_answer_cricle));
            }
  }else if(startTestDetailsModel.getResult().get(position).getType().equals("question") && startTestDetailsModel.getResult().get(position).getAnswerClicked()==3){
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                holder.answerOneRB.setBackground(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.round_answer_cricle));
                holder.answerTwoRB.setBackground(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.round_answer_cricle));
                holder.answerThreeRB.setBackground(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.round_answer_cricle_solid));
                holder.answerFourRB.setBackground(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.round_answer_cricle));
            }
  }else if(startTestDetailsModel.getResult().get(position).getType().equals("question") && startTestDetailsModel.getResult().get(position).getAnswerClicked()==4){
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                holder.answerOneRB.setBackground(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.round_answer_cricle));
                holder.answerTwoRB.setBackground(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.round_answer_cricle));
                holder.answerThreeRB.setBackground(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.round_answer_cricle));
                holder.answerFourRB.setBackground(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.round_answer_cricle_solid));
            }
  }
```

Comment: try it now... I had not used the postion to set the answerClicked in the click listeners

Comment: I forgot to notify the data set change ... my bad

Comment: It's working bro. I have just modified your code now it's working. Thanks for help @Kushan

Comment: Sure man... Mark as answered so others dont keep answering :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you added these method in recyclview Adapter:

```
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update anything in adapter, then you have to update list model item & then apply condition in `onBindViewHolder` to apply changes.Just like that :

```
holder.questoinTV.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                   boolean abc = list.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getAbcItem();
                   list.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).setAbcItem(!abc);
                   notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });



 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
      if (holder instanceof MyViewHolder){
            if(list.get(position).getAbcItem())
                  ((MyViewHolder) holder).questoinTV.setBackground(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.round_answer_cricle));
            else  ((MyViewHolder) holder).questoinTV.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
      }
}
```

Comment: I am not updating anything in model i just need to display selected element in recyclerView  list